# Codename One Capture API correct usage

Tags: codenameone

I tried to use the following code with the purpose to record some videos with real devices (Android and iPhone) and to see the resulting file sizes. But it doesn't work... it seems to record, but it doesn't play the resulting videos neither on Android nor iOS.

I wrote the following code merging some examples in the Codename One API. What's wrong?

```
    Form hi = new Form("Capture", BorderLayout.center());
    Container cnt = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
    hi.setToolbar(new Toolbar());
    Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Title");
    FontImage icon = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_VIDEOCAM, s);

    FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
    String recordingsDir = fs.getAppHomePath() + "recordings/";
    fs.mkdir(recordingsDir);
    try {
        for (String file : fs.listFiles(recordingsDir)) {
            Button mb = new Button(file.substring(file.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) + " - " + (int) (fs.getLength(recordingsDir + file) / 1024.0 / 1024.0 * 100) / 100.0 + " MB");
            mb.addActionListener((e) -> {
                try {
                    Media video = MediaManager.createMedia(recordingsDir + file, true);
                    hi.removeAll();
                    hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, new MediaPlayer(video));
                    hi.revalidate();
                } catch (IOException err) {
                    Log.e(err);
                }
            });
            cnt.add(mb);
        }
        hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, cnt);

        hi.getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar("", icon, (ev) -> {
            try {
                String file = Capture.captureVideo();
                if (file != null) {
                    SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd-kk-mm");
                    String fileName = sd.format(new Date());
                    String filePath = recordingsDir + fileName;
                    Util.copy(fs.openInputStream(file), fs.openOutputStream(filePath));
                    Button mb = new Button(file.substring(file.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) + " - " + (int) (fs.getLength(filePath) / 1024.0 / 1024.0 * 100) / 100.0 + " MB");
                    mb.addActionListener((e) -> {
                        try {
                            Media video = MediaManager.createMedia(filePath, true);
                            hi.removeAll();
                            hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, new MediaPlayer(video));
                            hi.revalidate();
                        } catch (IOException err) {
                            Log.e(err);
                        }
                    });
                    cnt.add(mb);
                    cnt.getParent().revalidate();
                }
            } catch (IOException err) {
                Log.e(err);
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException err) {
        Log.e(err);
    }
    hi.show();
```

This is what I see on iPhone X after tapping a Button to open a recorded video (that is very similar to what I see on Android 7):

[image]

Comment: What isn't working? Don't you see a play button on the media player?

Comment: I've just updated the question adding a screenshot.

Comment: Another information: the above code works in the Simulator, but it doesn't work in real iPhone and Android devices.

Comment: I'm actually seeing worse behavior on my One Plus 6 with pie which might mean there is a regression on pie with video playback. I've pulled out an older device and testing it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent so much time looking at this it's embarrassing...

Change this:

```
Form hi = new Form("Capture", BorderLayout.center());
```

To this:

```
Form hi = new Form("Capture", new BorderLayout());
```

The former gives the component its preferred size. The latter scales it to take up available space. The preferred size is zero on most platforms since the video needs to load for preferred size to apply. When it loads one would need to reflow the layout.

Comment: Thank you very much, however this is not fully resolutive, because when I tap a button to play a recorded video I get a blank black screen. I tried to add `mediaPlayer.setAutoplay(true);` but it seems to work on Android, but not on iOS (in the Simulator I've seen that the position of `setAutoplay` in the code, before or after adding the mediaplayer to the container, makes a difference). Maybe there are other issues in my code. I'll investigate better.

Comment: Try adding the mp4 extension so we can detect the right mime type of the file.